# Can't get parameter from the page via servlet

Tags: java, servlets

It should be simple, but i have a problem,
This is my *.jsp file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit DataBase data</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hr size="2"/>
    <h2>id in DB = ?</h2>
    <p>id:<input type="text" name="id" size="20" value="sdfs"></p>
    <p>
    <form action="/web/save" method="POST">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet looks like this

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      String id = request.getParameter("id")
      System.out.println("ID=" + id);
      }
```

but in output ID=null

servlet was loaded by the button click on the server

Comment: You data is misleading. Please paste these files in this order 
1. Source JSP File (The form piece alone is enough) 2. Target Servlet (The doPost function Alone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the input tag in between the form tags.

Answer (score 0):

For the code you put here

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

is correct.

Check, you might have put

```
<form action="" method="GET">
```

Comment: It seems the method gets called when he submits.